# Write a function keyPair(obj1, obj2, key) that accepts two objects and a key string as arguments. bj1 and obj2

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

> Write a function `key Pair(obj1, obj2, key)` that accepts two objects and a key string as arguments.
> The function should return an array containing the values of the given key in `obj1` and `obj2`.

```js
function keyPair(obj1, obj2, key) {
  let arr = [];

  for (let key in obj1) {
    if (key === 'name') {
      arr.push(obj1[key]);
      arr.push(obj2[key]);
    }
  }

  return arr;
}

let cat1 = { name: 'jinkee', breed: 'calico' };
let cat2 = { name: 'garfield', breed: 'red tabby' };

console.log(keyPair(cat1, cat2, 'breed')); // [ 'calico', 'red tabby' ]
console.log(keyPair(cat1, cat2, 'name')); // [ 'jinkee', 'garfield ]
```

someone should give me a little guide have been struggling with it. Thanks

Comment: And the problem is? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you needed to do was *not* check for the property being `name` and not loop over every property and it works exactly as expected

```js
function keyPair (obj1, obj2, key) {
      let arr = [];
  
      arr.push(obj1[key]);
      arr.push(obj2[key]);
  
      return arr;
  }

  
  let cat1 = { name: 'jinkee', breed: 'calico' };
  let cat2 = { name: 'garfield', breed: 'red tabby' };
  console.log(keyPair(cat1, cat2, 'breed')); // [ 'calico', 'red tabby' ]
  console.log(keyPair(cat1, cat2, 'name')); // [ 'jinkee', 'garfield ]
```

The code can also be significantly shortened

```js
const keyPair = (obj1, obj2, key) => [obj1[key], obj2[key]]

  
  let cat1 = { name: 'jinkee', breed: 'calico' };
  let cat2 = { name: 'garfield', breed: 'red tabby' };
  console.log(keyPair(cat1, cat2, 'breed')); // [ 'calico', 'red tabby' ]
  console.log(keyPair(cat1, cat2, 'name')); // [ 'jinkee', 'garfield ]
```